# QMessageBox and beep after migrate from 4 to 5 qt

Tags: qt, qt4

After migrate project from Qt4 to Qt5 version on Windows OS lost "beep" sound on QMessageBox::(information/critical/warning/question) function. Hove can I retrieve it?

Comment: Maybe call `QApplication::beep()`?

Comment: As an option. And whether it is global in application setting "beep on QMessageBox dialog"?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing, but you can subclass QMessageBox and provide something to call QApplication::beep() when you show messagebox. Is it correct solution for you?

Comment: Probably will do so. Thanks

Comment: In this case I added this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option to enable beep sound in `QMessageBox`. But you can use `QApplication::beep()` when you show message box.

If you don't want call `beep()` where you show message box and if you you think that you really need this, you can subclass `QMessageBox` and add some method which will call `QApplication::beep()`