# Notification sound in QDialog

Tags: qt, audio, qdialog

Is there any way to play notification sound like in QMessageBox::Information when I call exec() of QDialog object in Qt?

It can be done with QSound but only with my own sound file, where in my case I need predefined notification sound from OS. (like in messagebox). I found messy workaround: Create messageBox in constructor of my QDialog only to play sound and quickly close it by singleShot timer. It works but it is messy and I think that it can be done much better.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `QApplication::beep`?

Comment: Oh man, it is so simple. Thanks a lot! Is it somewhere sound for error? I didn't find it in QApplication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`QApplication::beep`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#beep):

> Sounds the bell, using the default volume and sound. The function is
>   not available in Qt for Embedded Linux.

Note that Qt5 does not anymore emit a beep when `QMessageBox::Information` is called as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997999/qmessagebox-and-beep-after-migrate-from-4-to-5-qt).